# How to create a graph of a building such that every node is a room?

Tags: json, graph

I'm working on a project and I need to create a graph for this huge building in which every node represent a room.
I'm wondering which is the best approach to create the graph, especially I'm wondering if exist some graphics tools that allow me to modelling the graph and then to export in some format like json.
Thanks everyone for the attention.

Comment: If you using node per room, what will the edges stand for? Do you have spesific language? There are many graph libraries

Comment: The edge will stand for the connection between the room, so in that way I can find the shortest path between two rooms. This will be part of the server side project and actually I'm working with node.js